# How do I write a function in a node.js file, and then call that function in a regular js file

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have initialized node in a folder, created my file, and written my function. In another folder, higher up the file system hierarchy, I wrote a script tag, with the source being the node.js file. I called the function, but as soon as I test it in a browser, I get this error:

```
resetPassword is not defined
```

Here is my node.js file code:

```
import { createRequire } from 'module';
const require = createRequire(import.meta.url);
var admin = require("firebase-admin");
var serviceAccount = require("./troop-30-elections-web-app-firebase-adminsdk-obsmr-61cc4bb59e.json");
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://troop-30-elections-web-app.firebaseio.com"
});

const resetPassword =(docId,newPass) => {
  return admin.auth().updateUser(docId, { 
    password: newPass
   })
  .then(() => {



return {"text": "User Password Successfully Updated"};  // this is what gets sent back to the app

  });
}
```

Here is my regular js code:

```
resetForm.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
        console.log("Step 1");
        e.preventDefault();
        let newPass = resetForm['reset-password'].value;
        resetPassword({docId: docId, newPass: newPass}).then(() => {
            const modal = document.querySelector('#modal-reset');
          M.Modal.getInstance(modal).close();
          resetForm.reset();
        });
        console.log("Step 1.5");
    });
```

Comment: The code you write in Node and the code you write in a browser are not always compatible with each other. Things like `module`, `require`, `fetch`, `navigator`, and `dns` only work in one or the other. Your code _could_ be compatible with both, but you should post it in your question so we can take a look.

Comment: define myFunction globally like `window.myFunction = function(){}` or `globals.myFunction = function(){}` depends on the environment and make sure the node.js script is loaded before the callee js

Comment: If you mean that you want to do something in node via a call from your browser, you're probably looking for a web server with which you can interact over HTTP requests.

Answer (score -2):

I think node uses ES5 syntax. I believe you haven't imported the function from one file to the other.
First, you might have to export the function from its home file, so that you can then import it in whatever file you want.

I think this link will help you out:
https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/getting-started/what-is-require/

Comment: Thank you. I think this is the right track, but not the exact solution yet. The file that calls the function is not written in node.js, just standard frontend javascript, so I cannot use Require.